# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined when press login button

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined

when I press on login button in my ionic2 and angular2 app.
I tried to look on variable that not intialize or function but I didn't find at all.

that's the login function

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage} from '@ionic/storage';

//components
import { MyService } from '../../providers/my-service';
import { AdminPage } from '../admin/admin';

/*
  Generated class for the ModalPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-modal-page',
  templateUrl: 'modal-page.html',
  providers:[MyService]
})
export class ModalPage {

  data:any;
  public local: Storage;
  private mydata:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private viewCtrl: ViewController,private service:MyService) {
    this.data={};
    this.data.username="";
    this.data.password="";
    this.local=new Storage();

  }

  login(){
    let username = this.data.username;
    let password = this.data.password;
    let data  = JSON.stringify({username, password});
    this.service.postLogin(data)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.mydata = data;
          this.local.set('username', this.mydata[0].name);
          this.local.set('token', this.mydata[0].token);
          this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
        }, error =>{
          console.log(error);
        })
  }
  dismiss(){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }

}
```

this is my-service page

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
import {NavController} from "ionic-angular";

import { AdminPage } from '../pages/admin/admin';
/*
  Generated class for the MyService provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  public local:Storage;
   private mydata:any;
    public getsession: any;
  constructor(public http: Http,private local: Storage,private navCtrl:NavController) {
    this.local=new Storage();

  }
  postLogin(data){
      let link = "http://adirzoari.16mb.com/newapi.php";
      return this.http.post(link,data)
          .map(res => res.json())
  }
  checkToken(){
      return this.getsession =this.local.get('token');

  }
}
```

[image: this is my error]

[image: when i press on the error-content-script.js]

[image: error shown]

Comment: Where do you get error? before postlogin or after getting response?

Comment: Btw the error is not in this file ...

Comment: after getting response.

Comment: @SteevePitis so where this error?

Comment: lol without your code I can't answer this question :p but the error is somewhere you call `**object**.element`

Comment: @steevePitis I agree with you but I don't have nothing with object.element..

Comment: @steevePitis look on my post again, I edit it and you can see everything I mean

Comment: Yes I saw, did you debug angular with some extension ? like batarang or something else ? try to disable them and test

Comment: @steevePitis sounds good but how I disable it? I'm trying but I don't see any option for it.

Comment: Go here : `chrome://extensions/`  ;)

Comment: then what to do? i don't see any extension i need to install

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you access a field 'element`somewhere in the template`modal-page.html`. For example,

```
{{ something.element }}
```

If so, try `{{ something?.element }}` instead.

This check if `something` exists (not null or undefined) before accessing a field.

Comment: I don't have any something.element \: look on my post again I edit it

Comment: Your last screenshot shows a function name `...ByFieldId(fieldId)`. Do **Pretty-print**( **{ }** below the code ) of the source file around this error and give it us. Or maybe you know this function and why it returns `undefined`

Comment: Zhytekvich - I don't have this function in my program at all. i don't have this file content-script.js.

Comment: what do you mean pretty print?

Comment: on your screenshot there curly braces below the source code, when you click it, it "un-minifies" the code. it's called "pretty-print". Also, this word is written above the source code.

Comment: I understand. this is what I see but I never see this page and I don't recognize this page in my project. I add to my post the photos from what you ask me to do. check the post again

Comment: do you have any solution? @Andrei Zhytkevich

Comment: @AdirZoari, what is the full trace stack for this error?

Comment: Zhytekvich - i wish i know.. i don't know what the reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124984/discussion-between-andrei-zhytkevich-and-adir-zoari).