# All declarations of ‘local' must have identical modifers in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I get this error when i use with `local:storage` variable.
I just want to notice that's it's just happened before an hour. Before that it worked well.

this error shown when I try to run the app by "ionic serve".
[image: error]

This is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {NavController} from "ionic-angular";

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
/*
  Generated class for the Myservice provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  public local:Storage;
  public getsession: any;


  constructor(public http: Http,private local: Storage,private navCtrl:NavController) {
    this.local=new Storage();

  }
  postLogin(data){
    let link = "http://adirzoari.16mb.com/login.php";
    return this.http.post(link,data)
        .map(res => res.json())
  }
  checkToken(){
    return this.getsession =this.local.get('token');

  }
  getData(){
    let link = "http://adirzoari.16mb.com/selectNotes.php";
    return this.http.get(link)
        .map(res=>res.json())
  }
  postInsert(data){
    let link="";
    return this.http.post(link,data)
        .map(res=>res.json())
  }
  postUpdate(data){
    let link="";
    return this.http.post(link,data)
        .map(res=>res.json())
  }
  postDelete(data){
    let link = "http://adirzoari.16mb.com/deleteNotes.php";
    return this.http.post(link,data)
        .map(res => res.json())
  }
}
```

in addition,
i get this error 
[image: new error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you also have local declared as `public local:Storage;` and also in the constructor as private as shown below:

```
constructor(public http: Http,private local: Storage,private navCtrl:NavController) {
```

## Fix

Delete `public local:Storage;`

Comment: thanks for comment, i changed it but i get new error  return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'observable'.... i just upload the photo and edit the post again

Answer (score 1):

> I changed it but I get new error return type of public method from
>   exported class has or is using name 'observable'...

In order to solve that issue, you need to explicitly import the `Observable` class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"; // <- add this import
import {NavController} from "ionic-angular";
```

Comment: thanks @sebferreras it solve my problem. can you please look on this new issue of my project? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856720/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-element-of-undefined-when-press-login

Comment: Glad I could help :) Sure, I'll take a look at it

Comment: @ sebaferreras thanks, hope you can find solution for me